# set value of html input elements by class with javascript in browser?

Tags: javascript, html

I need set value of a bunch of input boxes based on class (class="Qty")

this works if I use the ElementID

```
document.getElementById('G_Qty_0').value='101'
```

but this doesn't work

```
document.getElementsByClassName('Qty').value='100'
```

What gives?

Cheers!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList`, not an individual element. You can loop through the list, e.g.:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('Qty');
var n;
for (n = 0; n < list.length; ++n) {
    list[n].value='100';
}
```

Or if you know there will be only one match (and you **know** there won't be zero matches):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('Qty')[0].value = '100';
```

You might also look at `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`, because they're actually better-supported than `getElementsByClassName` (specifically: IE8 supports them, but doesn't have `getElementsByClassName`). `querySelector` looks for the *first* element in the document that matches the given CSS selector and returns that element instance (or `null` if there are none). `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` of all matching elements. (That `NodeList` is not quite the same as the one returned by `getElementsByClassName`, in that it's a snapshot as of when you make the call, not a live `NodeList`).

So for instance:

```
document.querySelector('.Qty').value = '100';
```

Or:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('.Qty');
var n;
for (n = 0; n < list.length; ++n) {
    list[n].value='100';
}
```

Comment: @MaxHodges - an easy reminder, if it says `getElements` with an **s**, it's always a nodeList.

Comment: @adeneo yes I understood that, just didn't know how to loop. I'm executing this in the browser console, and thought it could be done in theory, but my JavaScript knowledge is pretty weak still.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question comes up among the first results on Google and I found a shorter solution, I'm writing it here for the benefit of those looking for a shorter code:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.Qty').forEach( (x) => { x.value = '100' } )
```